# Python - regex returns differently in method than on its own

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, file-io, directory

This takes a directory (sample list of files below) and parses for anything that matches a proper format (below), fixes anything with extra or lacking whitespace (here's the problem), and appends anything that falls through with a distinguishing symbol.  The problem is that the regex works fine on it's own, but there may be some issue in my `checkProper()` method that is very not obvious to me.  It works to separate files already in proper format (in the first part of loop) but then seems to not work when checking anything that was fixed.  It seems like the problem is in the loop somewhere and not the fixing regex (re.sub) because I've tried with several other methods and gotten the same result (goodFix[] is empty).  This should be fixing those files and it's not.

proper format:

```
201308 - (82608) - MAC 2233-007-Methods of Calculus - Lastname, Firstname.pdf
```

sample list of files in directory:

```
201308 (82608)  MAC 2233-007-Methods of Calculus - Lname, Lee.txt
201308 - (12345) - ABC 2233L-007-course Name - last, first.txt
201308 - (12345) - XYZ 2233L-007-course Name 1 - last, first.txt
201308 - (82422) - MAA 5228-001- Introductory Analysis 1 - Zhang, Xiaodong.txt
201308 - (82429) - MAC 1105-004-College Algebra - Somelastname, Jesse.txt
201308 - (82490) - MAC 2311-003-Calculus and Analytic Geometry 1 - Lastname, Heinrich.txt
201308 - (82608) - MAC 2233-007-Methods of Calculus - Lname, Lee.txt
201308 - (82609) - MAC 2233L-007-Methods of Calculus 1 - Lname, Lee.txt
201308 - (96144) - STA 3173-001 - Introduction to Biostatistics - Qian, Lianfen.txt
201308 - (96381) - MAT 1033-023 -I ntemediate Algebra - Escuder, Ana.txt
201308 - (96444) - MAC 2313-009 - Calculus and Analytic Geometry 3 - Locke, Stephen.txt
@ 201308  -  @ '  ;  ,, @ 45 - 12 - xyz - mno  -  123.txt
```

Note above that "Qian, Escuder, Locke" are examples of files that should be corrected to proper format and are not.

Methods:

```
def readDir(path1):
    return [ f for f in os.listdir(path1) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path1,f)) ]

def checkProper(f,term):
    return re.match(term + '\s-\s\(\d{5}\)\s-\s\w{3}\s\d{4}\w?-\d{3}-[^\.]+\s-\s[^\.]+\.txt', f)

def regexSubFix(f,term):
    return re.sub(term + '\s*-\s*(\(\d{5}\))\s*-\s*(\w{3}\s\d{4}\w?-\d{3}-(?:[^.\s]|\b\s\b)+)\s*-\s*([^.]+\.txt)$', r' - \1 - \2 - \3', f)

def regexFindallFix(f):
    return ' - '.join(str(elem) for elem in re.findall(r'^(\d+)\s*-\s*(\(\d+\))\s*-\s*(.*?)\s*-\s*(\S+,.*)$', f)[0])

def properFiles(dir1,term,path1):
    goodMatch = []; stillWrong = []; goodFix = [] #; fixed = ""
    for f in dir1:
        result = checkProper(f,term)
        if result: goodMatch.append(result.group(0))
        else:
            #fixed = re.sub(r"(?<=[0-9]) *- *(?=[^0-9a-zA-Z])", " - ", re.sub(r"(?<=[^0-9]) *- *(?=[0-9a-zA-Z])", " - ", f))
            #fixed = parseFix(f)
            #fixed = regexFindallFix(f)
            fixed = regexSubFix(f,term)
            print "^^^^^^   ",fixed
            if checkProper(fixed,term):
                os.rename(path1+'\\'+f, path1+'\\'+fixed); goodFix.append(f)
            else: os.rename(path1+'\\'+f, path1+'\\'+'@ '+f); stillWrong.append(f)
        #print "f ---- ",f
    goodToGo = len(goodMatch)+len(goodFix); total = len(dir1)
    print "%d total files. %d files in proper format. %f%% success rate."%(total,goodToGo,(goodToGo/(float(total)))*100.0)
    print "All files not in proper format are appended with @ to be clearly marked for the user."
    return goodMatch, goodFix, stillWrong
```

When called in main, `readDir()` provides the list of files in the directory to passed into `properFiles()`. 
`regexSubFix()` is the method used now, but with `regexFindallFix()` and another method, the result was the same (and nothing appended to `goodFix[]`).  `checkProper()` appears to be working fine in the everything else but then the last if statement doesn't seem to catch the `fixed` files.

I'm learning Python, so I'm fairly sure a junior programmer can spot this quickly, but if any pro happens across this question I'm sure this is cake for them.

EDIT:
These files have improper whitespace and but are not fixed for some reason:

```
201308 - (82442) - MAC 1105 - 012 - College Algebra - Harmon, Drake.txt
```

Comment: Hi again ^^ Seems like those three dummies are exceptional ones... Could you put in your question what should they become ideally? I think you'll need a different fix method for those. For now, I think that the parts like `3173-001 - Introduction` should become `3173-001-Introduction` and that shouldn't be too much of a problem, but changing `1033-023 -I ntemediate` to `1033-023-Intemediate` might require some assumptions, and it'll be harder if you have something like `1033-023 -I ntem edi ate`...

Comment: Hi thanks for stopping by, I know it's a bit of a mess in there. The dummies are just to make sure that something completely wrong is appended with '@', nothing to fix there.  As for `023 -I ntem` and such, it would seem like some API with access to 'most likely word matches' or something similar would fix, but for now this has to run on a basic workstation that may not allow connections to databases, etc through it's firewall and so I'm not really concerned about this for now.  Mostly I just need everything fixable to be renamed to the fixed string.

Comment: Oh, oops, right, I understand what you're doing better now and I agree that it should be working. Hmm, could you try rawing your regex? I just noticed that `checkProper` and `regexSubFix` aren't rawed. When I didn't understand python's regex at all, I used to get weird things.

Comment: You mean `re.sub(term + r'...')` I think? Added the `r` to both the sub and the match regex's and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I found the problem:

To fix what can be fixed, make this your regexSubFid def:

```
def regexSubFix(f,term):
    return re.sub(term + r'\s*-\s*(\(\d{5}\))\s*-\s*(\w{3}\s\d{4}\w?\s*-\s*\d{3}\s*-\s*(?:[^.\s]|\b\s\b)+)\s*-\s*([^.]+\.txt)$',
          lambda match: term+' - {0} - {1} - {2}'.format(match.group(1),
          re.sub(r'\s*-\s*', '-', match.group(2)),
          match.group(3)) ,
          f)
```

Next, change the if part to this:

```
if checkProper(fixed,term):
    goodFix.append(fixed)
else: stillWrong.append(fixed)
```

The only thing left, is that you have this file which became this:

```
201308 - (96381) - MAT 1033-023-I ntemediate Algebra - Escuder, Ana.txt
```

Comment: I'll be gone for some time now, nighttime here and it;s past 1am ^^;

Comment: There was a file in 1 of the main directories that didn't take, I added it above if you want to take a look. But otherwise yes thanks again, it works so much better now. It worked at like 75% success rate in a copy of 1 of the major directories, that's genius. It's dinner time here in Florida, 6pm.

Comment: @stackuser Okay, can you try the edited regex? The issue was at this part: `\w?-\d{3}` which I changed to this: `\w?\s*-\s*\d{3}` to allow those spaces. ^^

Comment: Oh it works nice now. 76% success rate. Thanks for everything (twice now). If, let's say, I wanted to allow the re.sub() to also fill in any of the 1st 3 hyphens that may be missing but should be discernible by the exact grouping of letters/numbers (so that after the 1st 6 digits there's a hyphen, etc.).  I'm wondering where would you adjust to make that possible. This would raise my success rate a lot more, but this might be a separate question and thread I'll open up later.

Comment: @stackuser I think that the 1st 2 hyphens should be relatively straightforward, if the first 6 digits and bracketed part is consistent. And I think that the third is currently being covered. 76% isn't that much high from the previous rate =P It's my pleasure ^^

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a simple logic inversion:

```
if checkProper(fixed,term):
    os.rename(path1+'\\'+f, path1+'\\'+fixed); goodFix.append(f)
```

This will replace the name with the proper version if checkProper does NOT match - so basically, this code says that if the name is valid, replace it, but if it's invalid, leave it alone. Simply swap the sense of the if:

```
if not checkProper(fixed,term):
    os.rename(path1+'\\'+f, path1+'\\'+fixed); goodFix.append(f)
```

and you should have it.

Comment: On the right track but no. It seems like inverting the logic will tell it to rename it to whatever was supposed to be fixed, only if it's not actually fixed.  I did try it though, just to be sure, and even the dummy (obviously wrong for testing purposes) filenames were left untouched (nothing was appended with '@')

Comment: you are right... misread it. can't use returns here. i tried using your re.sub, and it didn't change any of the text - the result of the re.sub was the same as the original text. re.match shows that for a sample (used the 'Escuder' line) that it didn't match, so that's why nothing was replaced.